# How to center form without changing layout

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a HTML form here which I have styled with CSS, I want the FORM to be in the exact center of the page, not fixed of course, but in the center. Whenever i tried to do this the layout of the fields and labels shift so I'm wondering how i can move the form and everything to the center without it changing the layout of everything inside.

```css
.form-style-1 {
  margin: 10px auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 20px 12px 10px 20px;
  font: 13px "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

.form-style-1 li {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.form-style-1 label {
  margin: 0 0 3px 0;
  padding: 0px;
  display: block;
  color: black;
}

.form-style-1 input[type=text],
.form-style-1 input[type=description],
textarea,
select {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 0px;
  outline: none;
}

.form-style-1 .field-divided {
  width: 25%;
}

.form-style-1 .field-long {
  width: 50%;
}

.form-style-1 .field-select {
  width: 50%;
}

.form-style-1 .field-textarea {
  height: 50px;
}

.form-style-1 input[type=submit] {
  background: #4B99AD;
  padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.form-style-1 input[type=submit]:hover {
  background: #4691A4;
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}

.form-style-1 .required {
  color: red;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #88;
}

.formb li {
  float: left;
}

.formb li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.formb li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<form class="move">
  <ul class="form-style-1">
    <li style="list-style: none; display: inline">
      <ul class="formb">
        <li>
          <a href="list.html">list Item</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="add.html">Add Item</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="edit.html">Edit Item</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="remove.html">Remove Item</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><label>Product Name and Number <span class="required">*</span>
    </label><input class="field-divided" name="field1" placeholder="Product" type="text">&nbsp;<input class="field-divided" name="field2" placeholder="Number" type="text"></li>
    <li><label>Description <span class="required">*</span></label>
      <input class="field-long" name="field3" type="description"></li>
    <li><label>Add Product</label> <select class="field-select" name="field4">
    <option value="Advertise">
     Macbook Air
    </option>
    <option value="Partnership">
     Macbook Pro
    </option>
    <option value="General Question">
     Macbook
    </option>
   </select></li>
    <li><label>Additional Comments <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
      <textarea class="field-long field-textarea" id="field5" name="field5"></textarea></li>
    <li><input type="submit" value="Submit"></li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your interface in the HTML. You have nested your navigation list inside your form. It doesn’t belong there.

`.form-style-1` ought to be in its own `nav` container and outside of the `form` container.

Fix that and come back with a reduced test case.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping your `li` in a `div` and giving property of `text-align:center` to your `div`

```
.form-box {
  text-align: center;
}

.form-box label {
  text-align:left;
  position:relative;
  left:100px;
}
```

I named your `div` as class `form-box`
Label is aligned on the left, you can change it the way you want, by removing or modifying those properties.

---

```css
.form-box {
  text-align: center;
}

.form-box label {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
}

.form-style-1 {
  margin: 10px auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 20px 12px 10px 20px;
  font: 13px "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

.form-style-1 li {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.form-style-1 label {
  margin: 0 0 3px 0;
  padding: 0px;
  display: block;
  color: black;
}

.form-style-1 input[type=text],
.form-style-1 input[type=description],
textarea,
select {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 0px;
  outline: none;
}

.form-style-1 .field-divided {
  width: 25%;
}

.form-style-1 .field-long {
  width: 50%;
}

.form-style-1 .field-select {
  width: 50%;
}

.form-style-1 .field-textarea {
  height: 50px;
}

.form-style-1 input[type=submit] {
  background: #4B99AD;
  padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.form-style-1 input[type=submit]:hover {
  background: #4691A4;
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}

.form-style-1 .required {
  color: red;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #88;
}

.formb li {
  float: left;
}

.formb li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.formb li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<form class="move">
  <ul class="form-style-1">
    <li style="list-style: none; display: inline">
      <ul class="formb">
        <li>
          <a href="list.html">list Item</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="add.html">Add Item</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="edit.html">Edit Item</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="remove.html">Remove Item</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <div class="form-box">
      <li><label>Product Name and Number <span class="required">*</span>
    </label><input class="field-divided" name="field1" placeholder="Product" type="text">&nbsp;<input class="field-divided" name="field2" placeholder="Number" type="text"></li>
      <li><label>Description <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input class="field-long" name="field3" type="description"></li>
      <li><label>Add Product</label> <select class="field-select" name="field4">
    <option value="Advertise">
     Macbook Air
    </option>
    <option value="Partnership">
     Macbook Pro
    </option>
    <option value="General Question">
     Macbook
    </option>
   </select></li>
      <li><label>Additional Comments <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
        <textarea class="field-long field-textarea" id="field5" name="field5"></textarea></li>
      <li><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button"></li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</form>
```